# Missing iOS Simulator List After Update

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I recently updated my VS2017 to 15.6.4 and now my device/simulators for iOS are missing...

[image]

They are all listed on my Mac, but are not being pulled to my PC.

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

More version info...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this by updating VS2017, as shown below...

[image]

Got to "Individual Components" and select the following...

[image]

It also appeared that I was a "dot" release behind my Mac. So I updated all to the latest stable. Which is what I did yesterday, but I guess it needed another round of updates after that and I missed it. All is working now. I hope this helps others.

PS - Remoted Simulator now works with Professional Edition. It brings the iSimulator to my windows box. Great stuff!